# Save thumbnail per field in model

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to save thumbnails on request for some fields in one model-class. The pain for me is, how do I manage to keep the thumbnail-class as simple as possible?

Let's say I've got this main-class

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img1 = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    ...
```

Now I'd like to save a thumbnail for each img-field in another model-class. So I'm able to query against `Thumbnail` if there is a thumb for e.g. `img1`...something like this (not working code)

```
class Thumbnail(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    field = models.FooBar('Staff._meta.fields...')
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path2)
```

Any suggestions or ideas of how this `Thumbnail`-class could look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest little more change to the models for better storing image and thumbnail.
You can create `ImageInfo` model that holds original image, thumbnail and any other attributes. It will have foriegnkey with `Staff` so that you can have multiple images for a `Staff`

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ImageInfo(models.Model):
    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path2)
```

Now you can find images which have thumbnail set are

```
staff_obj.imageinfo_set.filter(thumb__isnull=False)
```